# how to work sql about MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
select distinct Id,srcId 
from schedule_mid as m 
where  Id > 100 and 
       not EXISTS ( select 1 from schedule_detail where id = m.srcId ) 
order  by srcId 
limit  500
```

In my opinion:  first  select one columns's Id and srcId 
               then   look whether Id > 100 and not,,,,,,,,
               then   look whether have 500 numbers 
                      if( >=500 ) then order by srcId and break;
               revert first

I just guess the result but i don't know whether right or wrong;

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what the question is and what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: it depends.
Read this for more information:
[click!](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html)